# Get feature vectors from BertForSequenceClassification

Tags: pytorch, embedding, bert-language-model

I have successfully build a sentiment analysis tool with `BertForSequenceClassification` from [huggingface/transformers](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) to classify $tsla tweets as positive or negative.

However, I can't find out how I can obtain the feature vectors per tweet (more specifically the embedding of `[CLS]`) from my finetuned model.

more info of used model:

```
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(OUTPUT_DIR, num_labels=num_labels)
model.config.output_hidden_states = True
tokenizer = BertTokenizer(OUTPUT_DIR+'vocab.txt')
```

However, when I run the code below the `output` variable only consists of the logits.

```
model.eval()
eval_loss = 0
nb_eval_steps = 0
preds = []

for input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids, label_ids in tqdm_notebook(eval_dataloader, desc="Evaluating"):
    input_ids = input_ids.to(device)
    input_mask = input_mask.to(device)
    segment_ids = segment_ids.to(device)
    label_ids = label_ids.to(device)

    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(input_ids,token_type_ids= segment_ids,attention_mask= input_mask)
```

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem after fine-tuning BertForSequenceClassification. I know your purpose is to get the hidden state of [CLS] as the representation of each tweet. Right? As the instruction of [API document](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html#tfbertforsequenceclassification), I think the code is:

```py
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(OUTPUT_DIR, output_hidden_states=True)
logits, hidden_states = model(input_ids, attn_masks)
cls_hidden_state = hidden_states[-1][:, 0, :] # the first hidden state in last layer
```

or

```py
model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(OUTPUT_DIR, output_hidden_states=True)
last_hidden_states = model.bert(input_ids, attn_masks)[0]
cls_hidden_state = last_hidden_states[:, 0, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

`BertForSequenceClassification` is a wrapper that consists of two parts: BERT model (attribute `bert`) and a classifier (attribute `classifier`).

You can call directly the underling BERT model. If you pass your input directly to it, you will get the hidden states. It returns a tuple: the first member of the tuple are all hidden states, the second one is the `[CLS]` vector.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution (see update question), but it only gives the logits. Do you now what the problem is?

Comment: Never mind, I used an older version of pytorch transformers that didn't allow the hidden states to be set to true :). I was able to extract them now. Thank you.